# Load Testing for authenticated website

Tags: authentication, testing, jmeter, load

How to test load on an authenticated website using Jmeter? 
There is a user login page on application start where we need to enter credentials to access the application.

Answer (score 0):

Just record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder),

JMeter will capture associated request(s) and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

If you will be lucky enough - you will be able to successfully replay the recorded script.

If not - most probably you will need to perform **correlation** - the process of extracting dynamic parameter from the previous response and adding it to the next request.

References:

- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Logging in to a web-site](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#logging_in)
- [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)